# Apache showing html folder instead of my index page on Debian

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I'm running Debian 8 with Apache 2.4 and it's installed in `/var/www/html` but when I go to my domain it shows `index of /` and my html folder instead of my index page.

Edit* index.html file is located in var/www/html/

Comment: Where is your index page stored? What is its filename? Is it readable by Apache? Please [edit] your question to include this information

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently upgrade from a previous version of Debian? You may need to change the `DocumentRoot` to be `/var/www/` instead of `/var/www/html`

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
Change the `DocumentRoot`, then
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Seems that in the new version of Debian the default location has changed

Edit: Here is a bug report detailing the change https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372

Edit2: 
Fix for this was changing `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html` as it was set to be `/var/www/` and index.html was in `/var/www/html`

Comment: I did not update Debian. Thats what I currently have /var/www/ for my DocumentRoot.

Comment: If you have `/var/www` as `DocumentRoot` and your `index.html` file is in `/var/www/html/` then you will need to move your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html` instead! Sorry, I had it the other way in my post

Comment: Ah it works now, thank you. What's weird is I haven't touched the DocumentRoot line and it was by default /var/www. Is there anymore configuring that needs to be done with apache? Because when I use to have shared hosting the layout seemed different.

Comment: That's quite strange that you haven't upgraded or touched it and its stayed like that. You'd have to review the apache and debian changelogs to see what else has changed. I've also noticed that a few things have moved around upgrading from Debian 7 to 8 (and upgrading apache to the latest) mainly just location of files